# VB6 - runtime error 48 with C/C++ dll

Tags: c, dll, vb6, runtime-error

First of all I want to say that I read most of the other questions here with similar issues before posting this question. But my situation is slightly different.

I have an old VB6 application which uses a custom C/C++ dll to send/read data over TCP.

The app is on a shared network drive of a win2003 server which multiple users can access. The dll sits in the application path and I use declare to load it.

VB6:

```
Public Declare Function Interface_Open Lib "Interface.dll" Alias "Open" As Integer
```

C/C++ dll:

```
_declspec(dllexport) int _stdcall Open() { }
```

Now for the strange part: The application runs smoothly for 90% of the time. But some users experience random the runtime error 48 "dll not found" while others dont.

It seems to fail when I try to call the dll:

```
Interface_Open
```

Im not able to replicate the error on my win7 64bit machine thats what confuses me. I also checked the network permissions for the users on the share but they were fine.

I don't think the problem lies inside the C/C++ code because logs tell me it failes before entering the dll.

Should I return a long value instead of an integer? Could this be a reason why it fails to load the dll?

Comment: Have you tried [this guy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281368/file-not-found-when-loading-dll-from-vb6/14455215#14455215)?

Comment: The standard issue is that it does not tell what DLL is not found.  Which tends to *not* be the DLL that you use, you'd know to look for a file named Interface.dll.  It is one that is used by this DLL.  Like the C runtime library.  Tends to work by accident, that DLL is often installed on the machine by somebody else.  If that doesn't help then ask the user to run SysInternals' Process Monitor.  It shows the program searching for the DLL and not finding it.

Answer (score -1):

Integers are 16 bit in VB, for compatability with 16 bit VB. So an integer in any other language is called a long in VB.

Comment: The idiot that did this, VB6 requires longs for Win32.